# Can't push items in mongo array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't push items into MongoDB array every time that i try to push a new element it creates an empty object and i cant figure out why,
I already used the

Collection.Array.push({element})&
Collection.save()

but i cant figure out a solution

**This is My Schema**

```
const Schema =  mongoose.Schema;

var ParticipantSchema = new Schema({

        nom:{Type:String},
        prenom:{Type:String},
        email:{Type:String}

})


var CompetitionSchema = new Schema({
    nom:String,
    date:Date,
    place:String,
    participant :[ParticipantSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Competition",CompetitionSchema);
```

**This is my funtion**

```
exports.addParticipant=function(req,res){


        var newParticipant={

            "nom":req.body.nom,
            "prenom":req.body.prenom,
            "email":req.body.email

        }

        Competition.updateOne(
            { _id:req.body.id}, 
            { $push: { participant: newParticipant } },
            (err,done)=>{
               return res.json(done)
            }
        );



}
```

the result is always an empty object like below

```
{
    "_id": "5ded0eeb85daa100dc5e57bf",
    "nom": "Final",
    "date": "2019-01-01T23:00:00.000Z",
    "place": "Sousse",
    "participant": [
        {
            "_id": "5ded0eeb85daa100dc5e57c0"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dee3c1b08474e27ac70672e"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: What you see is not an empty object, mongoose just does not "populate" sub-documents by default . By default you'll only see the _id of the subdocument. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: @PascalLamers  he uses participant as embedded, not a seperate collection.

Comment: But the collection is filled with sub documents.

Comment: @SuleymanSah He uses another schema inside the array, according the example in docs this results in subdocuments. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: so how can i fix this problem, Thank you

Comment: @AbdessalemLetaief I found the problem, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your code, the only problem is that in schema definition  you have `Type`, but it must be `type`.

If you update your ParticipantSchema like this, it will work:

```js
var ParticipantSchema = new Schema({
  nom: { type: String },
  prenom: { type: String },
  email: { type: String }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using another Schema in the Array. This results in so-called subdocuments (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). Mongoose does not populate subdocuments by default. So all you see is just the `_id`. You can use the populate method to see all subdocuments in detail. ( https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html ) .

Example :

```js
Competition.
  find({}).
  populate('participant').
  exec(function (err, comps) {
     //
  });
```

You can either use `populate` on the Model or on the Document. For populating a document, take a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate . There is also a `auto-populate` plugin available via `npm` but in most cases it's not necessary : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate .

Comment: This does not answer the question. The problem was in schema definition as described in my answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah you are correct ! I mixed up `sucdocuments` with `referenced documents` .